# \texttt in tikz plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

is there a way to make it works correctly? Seems that the use of \texttt doesn't work

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    symbolic x coords={\texttt{cv}, \texttt{pT}, $\widetilde{pT}$,, \texttt{ev}, \texttt{ev(cv)}},
    ylabel={CI (\%)},
    xtick={\texttt{cv}, \texttt{pT}, $\widetilde{pT}$,, \texttt{ev}, \texttt{ev(cv)}},
    xticklabel style={rotate=90}]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (\texttt{cv},26.355)
        ($\widetilde{pT}$,100)
        (\texttt{pT},35.55114)
    };
    \addplot[ybar,fill=orange] coordinates {
        (\texttt{ev(cv)},63.17104)
        (\texttt{ev},93.775)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Note that you will not need the `figure` env for your example.

Comment: Seems to compile just fine if I remove t the `xtick` line. The xticks will then just be the symbolic ones.

Comment: @daleif Indeed! I always thought that it is safer not to use macros in symbolic coordinates though ... Seems that it still works in certain (simpler) cases ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht some of the internals in `pgfplots` can be rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe not style symbolic coordinates (although this might work in certain cases). But you surely can style their labels:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    symbolic x coords={cv, pT, pTn,, ev, evcv},
    ylabel={CI (\%)},
    xticklabels={, \texttt{cv}, \texttt{pT}, $\widetilde{pT}$,, \texttt{ev}, \texttt{ev(cv)}},
    xticklabel style={rotate=90}]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (cv,26.355)
        (pTn,100)
        (pT,35.55114)
    };
    \addplot[ybar,fill=orange] coordinates {
        (evcv,63.17104)
        (ev,93.775)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]